# Units in Sass mixin are not working as intended

Tags: html, css, sass, scss-mixins

I wrote this mixin and I'm really not sure why is it not working as intended.

```
@mixin responsive($breakpoint){

    @if $breakpoint == xs {
        @media only screen and (max-width:35.99875em ) { 
            @content 
        } 
    }

    @if $breakpoint == sm {
        @media only screen and (min-width:35.99876em) and (max-width:47.99875em) { 
            @content
        } 
    } 

    @if $breakpoint == md {
        @media only screen and (min-width:47.99876‬em) and (max-width:61.99875‬em) { 
            @content 
        } 
    } 

    @if $breakpoint == lg {
        @media only screen and (min-width:61.99876‬em) and (max-width:74.99875‬em) { 
            @content 
        } 
    } 

    @if $breakpoint == xl {
        @media only screen and (min-width:74.99876em) and (max-width:85.37375em) { 
            @content 
        } 
    }  

    @if $breakpoint == xxl {
        @media only screen and (min-width:85.37376‬em) { 
            @content 
        } 
    }  

}
```

Here everything seems fine, but in VSC some "ems" are not highlighted and those "ems" that are not highlighted are not working correctly. (see image 1)

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tssF1.png)

When I compile sass, it is not showing any errors, but the "ems" remain grey even in CSS code.

Below code is example usage of mixin.

```
body {

    @include responsive(xxl){
        background: rgb(147, 48, 228);
    }

    @include responsive(xl){
        background: rgb(44, 255, 150);
    }

    @include responsive(lg){
        background: rgb(255, 245, 100);
    }

    @include responsive(md){
        background: rgb(255, 146, 146);
    }

    @include responsive(sm){
        background: rgb(145, 145, 145);
    }

    @include responsive(xs){
        background: #000;
    }

}
```

Below code is compiled sass in CSS file.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 85.37376‬em) {
  body {
    background: #9330e4; } }

@media only screen and (min-width: 74.99876em) and (max-width: 85.37375em) {
  body {
    background: #2cff96; } }

@media only screen and (min-width: 61.99876‬em) and (max-width: 74.99875‬em) {
  body {
    background: #fff564; } }

@media only screen and (min-width: 47.99876‬em) and (max-width: 61.99875‬em) {
  body {
    background: #ff9292; } }

@media only screen and (min-width: 35.99876em) and (max-width: 47.99875em) {
  body {
    background: #919191; } }

@media only screen and (max-width: 35.99875em) {
  body {
    background: #000; } }
```

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx58f.png)

At first I thought those "em" highlighting is just in VSC , but when i open browser and look in debugger I get the same result, still those "ems" are not highlighted as intended. (see image 3)

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11ws3.png)

Now when i comment "ems" that are not highlighted and just rewrite the same thing in CSS file, it works without any problems. (see image 4)

[image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDdTh.png)

Here is an example with sass compiled CSS file. (see gif 1)

[gif 1](https://gyazo.com/9331a0f611f3be43f1c89022ec22aa8d)

And here is an example with same breakpoints and values just written in CSS from start. (see gif 2)

[gif 2](https://gyazo.com/421aca39ae37d87a071d402d6554dbcd)

Looking at the posted question, it seems that those "ems" that are not working, are not highlighted in stack overflow as well.

I forgot to mention that rewriting the same breakpoint fixes the issue, but can anyone explain why was this happening at first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have ‬ (Pop Directional Formatting) characters in your SASS code between some of the numeric values and "em".  Values such `85.37376‬em` are actually in your code as `85.37376&#8236;‬em` .

Please inspect the generate CSS in Chrome's dev tools. I attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQt8y.png).

Syntax highlighting in VSCode is further corrected when you add semicolons after each of the content rules:  `@content;`

Comment: I don't think that was the issue, since mixin is working fine without ";" and when i put ";", those "ems" are still greyed and not working as intended.

Comment: Yes you are right, it does the improve syntax highlighting in VSC of the rest of the mixin, but not the em-value issue you are asking about. Found the issue though: you have some  &#8236; (Pop Directional Formatting) characters in your code between the numeric values and the em units. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Well.. I didn't expect that to be an issue if I'm completely honest, I'm also not really sure how that thing got there in first place and why was it not showing in VSC, anyways thank you for  help, I've lost almost 2 days trying to figure this out..